# Get XP to automatically "press" the default button on a dialog box

Tags: windows-xp, dialog, registry

Some time ago, I came across an online article that described how to configure Windows XP to automatically accept the default option on a dialog box. As I (vaguely) recall, it was some sort of oddball registry configuration that did this, and it amazingly worked. Yeah - it's dangerous, but it would be very helpful right now with a problem where I'm trying to run Windows XP in an unattended situation. I'm trying to suppress any kind of interaction.

So if you can point me to the magic incantation to repeat this, I'd appreciate it. I'm sure I saved the link, only it's at least 2 hard disk crashes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this again later. There's a registry entry called "EnableDefaultReply" that can be used to control this functionality. An MSDN article with extensive detail, cleverly called ["Enabling Default Reply"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940850.aspx) can be found at that link.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if XP can do that, but give [Buzof from Basta Computing](http://www.basta.com/Product.aspx?pid=13) a try. Works very well for what you have in mind.

Maybe you recall setting the option of the mouse pointer to the default button?