# Tools/code to automatically click ok on dialogs

Tags: windows, windows-xp, automation, dialog

We have an 'enterprisey' system with a scheduling component which gets floored if any dialogs come up. If any modal dialogs come up in the processes it is running, it gets 'paused' and can't kick off any new processes.

Excuse me a minute ...

*goes outside*
*laughs*
*cries*
*comes back*

.. ahem ... so anyway we need some sort of tool/technique that can lurk in the background and automatically detect specific dialogs and click OK on them. Any recommendations?

The offending system is running in Windows XP.

(NB: changing the third-party-enterprisey system or making its developers sit on the naughty step until they improve it are not options in the short term)

Comment: Sorry for removing the [enterprisey] tag, but it doesn't really add information (it's similar to the [wtf] tag in this way).

Comment: I disagree. enterprisey Tefers to a specific subset of "wtf" problems, and it's useful to identify a certain category of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219146/get-xp-to-automatically-press-the-default-button-on-a-dialog-box) I found:

[Buzof by Basta Computing](http://www.basta.com/Product.aspx?pid=13)

which did the trick.

There is also a product called [DialogDevil](http://www.dialogdevil.com/index.php) which looked promising but didn't work in our situation for some reason.

Comment: I followed your advice and I must say Buzof is really easy to use. You just click on the dialogue you want to OK and it automatically closes it. It takes seconds to set up and is much easier than AutoIT. Thanks for the useful advice!

Comment: For me, Buzof only worked for the first time of a message box appearing (inside Visual Studio .NET when registering an Add-in-Express project).

Answer (score 3):

[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is absolutely perfect for this. You can use the tool to help identify the dialog, write your own simple code and distribute the "auto clicker" via exe. It lurks in the background by running from the task tray.

Answer (score 0):

DialogDavil will require exact same parameters on your dialog (for which you want buttons to be autoclicked) every time that same dialog pops up. And thats why it didnt work for me in first pass. Then i changed the control file at the following path to remove the changing items (a text box text in my case)
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\DAIR\DialogDevil\control.xml
And then it worked like a charm.
HTH,